# Partially commutative elements in powers of augmentation ideal

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, free-groups, noncommutative-rings, group-rings

Let $\vartheta$ a relation of parcial commutation over a set $X,$ and consider the respective free parcially commutative group $F(X, \vartheta).$ Let $K[F(X, \vartheta)]$ the parcially commutative free group ring. Let
$$\varepsilon \colon K[F(X, \vartheta)] \to K$$
$$ \sum\limits_{\overline{x} \in F(X, \vartheta)} \alpha_{\overline{x}} \overline{x} \mapsto \sum\limits_{\overline{x} \in F(X, \vartheta)} \alpha_{\overline{x}}$$
We define in $K[F(X, \vartheta)]$ the augmentation ideal $\mathfrak{X} = \ker(\varepsilon).$

Denote by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \omega}$ the Fox derivative, with $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j} = \delta_{ij}$ for $x_i \in K[F(X)],$ and

$$\frac{\partial^n f}{\partial x_{j_n}\partial x_{j_{n-1}} \cdots \partial x_{j_{1}} } = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j_n}} \left(  \frac{\partial^{n-1} f}{\partial x_{j_{n-1}} \cdots \partial x_{j_{1}} }  \right) 
$$

Also, $\varphi \colon K[F(X)] \to K[F(X, \vartheta)]$ is defined by $\varphi(x_i) =\overline{x_i},$ for $x_i \in F(X).$

We can define a derivation in $K[F(X, \vartheta)],$ letting $D(\overline{x_i}) = \overline{x_1}-1$ for $\overline{x_i} \in F(X, \vartheta)$ and

$$
D(\overline{f}) = \sum\limits_i \varphi\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right) (\overline{x_i} - 1)$$

How can I prove that $\overline{f} \in R[F(X, \vartheta)]$ is in $\mathfrak{X}^n$ iff $$\varepsilon\left( \varphi\left(\sum\limits_{\omega \in \overline{\omega}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \omega}\right) \right) = 0 \quad \forall \overline{\omega} \in F(X, \vartheta), |\overline{\omega}|\le n-1?$$

Comment: would you mind giving a reference for partial commutation relations?

Comment: This seems to be the same question as on Mathematics: [Partially commutative elements in powers of augmentation ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3278064).
I think that [this answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se#2638) contains very reasonable advice about [meta-tag:cross-posting], the most important point is probably that the poster should include the link to the other copies.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind when using the two sites is that there are some differences between the tag systems. For example, on MO it is [recommended to use one of the top-level tags](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/frequently-asked-questions-about-tagging-on-mathoverflow/1076#1076) and the tag (abstract-algebra) is [deprecated](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/abstract-algebra/info).